# NgRx: Is the RxJS pipe operator necessary for store.select?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I came across a piece of code that had a pipe operator, but there wasn't a chain. Is it necessary? or any benefit to it at all?

with pipe

```
this.store.pipe(select(currentUser)).subscribe(authState => {});
```

without pipe

```
this.store.select(currentUser).subscribe(authState => {});
```

Comment: RxJS 6 introduced pipeable operators. The old method without `pipe` is deprecated https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/91088dae1df097be2370c73300ffa11b27fd0100/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: This is not true guys, it was un-deprecated in NgRx 7, see https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is a bit confusing. in NgRx 6 the `select()` method was deprecated in favor of `select()` operator. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/6.1.2/modules/store/src/store.ts#L22-L24.

However, since NgRx 7 it was un-deprecated:

- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361
- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1382
- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-16
  *store: remove deprecation from `Store.select`*

The official doc for NgRx is using the `select()` operator but people in [#1361](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361) recommend using the `select()` method.

Comment: So as of right now pipe does not need to be used in the select, but both can technically be used? The link you provided shows users recommend select without the pipe operator.

Comment: You can use both but since one of the maintainers of NgRx recommends using the method variant I'd do that as well. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361#issuecomment-457213242

Comment: You can indeed use both. I assume the reason it was not deprecated is because this method doesn't really need to be tree shaked. If you use the store without ever using `select` something's probably really odd

Comment: From the discussion on GitHub my understanding is that RxJS team discourages from extending RxJS classes because it only leads to hard to find bugs and it might not be even possible since RxJS 7. NgRx `Store` class is extending RxJS `Observable` in order to provide the `pipe()` method so they had to undeprecate `select()` method that only returns an instance of Observable.